# Printing out objects

Tags: java

I want to print out the individual values of my objects.Say i just want to print firstname of one the objects, not of all of them, how would i do this?. you will see in the code i never gave my objects individual names so how would i refer to them?

I have already added the string override method thing.

I am not sure what the names of my objects would be so i can't refer to them individually.

i have a seperate class with the student object, and the readFile method is reading a text file and creating a new object.

so how would i refer to this objects using `system.out.println`?

```
public static boolean readFile(String filename) 
{ 
    File file = new File(filename);

    try
    {
          List<Student> list = new ArrayList<>();   
          Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
          while(scanner.hasNextLine())
        {
              String[] words = scanner.nextLine().split(",");
              list.add(new Student(words[0],words[1],words[2], new String[ {words[3],words[4],words[5],words[6],words[7]} ]);
        }
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)   
    { 
        System.out.println("Failed to read file");
      }
      return true;

}

    public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
        readFile("C:\\temp\\studentdata.txt");
        displayMenu();      
    }

    private static void displayReportByMarks() 
   {
          System.out.println(Student.id);
     }
```

cannot make static reference to non static field.

Comment: Which line exactly is giving you this error?

Comment: Your code does not make sense, sorry.
There is no method 'displayMEnu', and the 'println' statement refers to a class instance variable, not a field.

Comment: last line System.out.println(Student.id);

Comment: just ignore the display menu

Comment: if only you knew how to use your constructors, getters and setters, you wouldnt be having this problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `Student` has a member `id`. This member belongs to an *instance*  of the class `Student`, not to the class itself. You can't access

```java
Student.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming standard capitalization rules:

`Student` is a class (i.e. a data type). When you call `Student.id` you are referring to the `id` of `Student`, not a specific `student` (notice capitalization).

If you want to print the id of a specific student, you need a **reference** to it. There are a few ways of doing this:

- Pass an instance of `Student` to your `displayReportByMarks()` function, so it becomes `displayReportByMarks(Student student)`
- Maintain a list of `Student`s and call `list.forEach(s -> System.out::println(s.id));`
- Similar to above, call `for (Student student : list) System.out.println(student.id);`

There are other issues with your code, but this is what is giving you the error "cannot make static reference to non static field".

I advise you read: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html . This is Oracle's documentation on the `static` keyword, what it means, and how to use it. I suggest you read this as it will help you understand this issue and prevent you making the same mistake in the future.